# check if list of values are inside a list of ranges (class by class)

Tags: r

I need to know if a given value (of a given class) is inside a range. I tried to solve my problem using apply and lapply together, but unsuccessfully.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Suppose "mylist" is a list of lists:

```
df1<-data.frame(classA=5.5,classB=6.3)
df2<-data.frame(classA=c(4.2,5.5),classB=c(5.1,6.2))
df3<-data.frame(classA=5.7,classB=4.2)
df4<-data.frame(classA=c(5.2,6.3),classB=c(4.0,5.0))
mylist<-list(list(df1,df2),list(df3,df4))
```

I expect the outcome to be something like this:

```
list(data.frame(TRUE,FALSE),data.frame(TRUE,TRUE))
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the range and class?

Comment: Sorry, seems like I wasn't very clear. The values of df1 could be compared to the values of df2. And df3 compared to df4. The toy data shows values from classes A and B (i.e. colnames of the dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an easier way to do this

```
btw <- function(val, vec) {
    purrr::map2_lgl(val, vec, ~dplyr::between(.x, .y[1], .y[2]))
}

purrr::map(mylist, ~btw(.x[[1]], .x[[2]]))

# [[1]]
# classA classB 
  # TRUE  FALSE 

# [[2]]
# classA classB 
  # TRUE   TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible sketch to design solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

# 1. Data set with elements
df_element <- data.frame(
  class_a = 5.5, 
  class_b = 6.3)

# 2. Data set with range for elements
df_range <- data.frame(
  class_a = c(4.2, 5.5), 
  class_b = c(5.1, 6.2))

# 3. Check if element is inside range of values
df_element$class_a %in% seq(min(df_range$class_a), max(df_range$class_a), by = 0.1)
df_element$class_b %in% seq(min(df_range$class_b), max(df_range$class_b), by = 0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks @andrii, but I'm afraid using seq will not work as the number can have several and unknown decimal plates

Comment: ok. it's just a sketch that can be useful in some way if you up it